# How do I fix this issue of Redis Exception in the controller custom attribute?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, stackexchange.redis

**StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException**: Timeout awaiting response
(outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 6266ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=EXISTS,
next: EXISTS 14061_last_hashed_request, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 1, aw: False,
bw: Inactive, rs: DequeueResult, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 4, out-pipe: 0,
serverEndpoint: 192.168.36.210:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 9 of 10 available,
clientName: LHLX0295(SE.Redis-v2.5.43.42402), IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000),
WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=13,QueuedItems=0,
CompletedItems=422), v: 2.5.43.42402 (Please take a look at this article for some
common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is too vague - what are you trying to do? Any code? From this it looks like Redis is timing out. Is the URL correct?